# How to import stl files into urdf files

Tags: ros, urdf, robot-model, solidworks, stl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use stl files with the tag mesh with this code:

```
  <geometry>
    <mesh filename="package://auriga_model/auriga_base.stl"/>
  </geometry>
```

The package existes and the file is located there but I get this message when I try to launch it:

```
[ERROR] [1301591093.704357996]: Malformed geometry for Visual element
[ERROR] [1301591093.704545807]: Could not parse visual element for Link '/base_laser'
[ERROR] [1301591093.704624976]: link xml is not initialized correctly
```

---

I have been doing some test with PR2 stl model and I had no success. Here are some of my tries:

```
  <!-- description of the robot -->
  <link name="/base_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.15 0 0.35"/>
      <geometry>
        <!-- mesh filename="package://auriga_model/meshes/auriga_base.stl" /-->
        <!-- mesh filename="package://auriga_model/meshes/head_pan.stl" /-->
        <mesh filename="package://pr2_description/meshes/head_v0/head_pan.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <link name="/base_laser">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </visual>
  </link>
```

For me, it looks like it can't resolve properly "filename="package://". Is it possible? I tested and "rospack find" command works fine with me.

Any clue?

---

Now I am able to load PR2 models but not the one of my robot. The original model was build in solidworks and maybe this is the problem. I will try to port it from Catia and I will say if it works.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9613/how-to-import-stl-files-into-urdf-files/) by [jsogorb](https://answers.ros.org/users/372/jsogorb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2011-03-31

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-04-07**:
If solidworks was the problem, one thing you can try is open the solidworks mesh in a text editor (e.g. vi), and replace the first word "solid" with spaces.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2011-03-31**:
That seems correct at first pass. What node are you launching that gives you this error? Also, could you post the whole Link xml, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The link "base_link" is just fine. The problem is that the second visual tag (in the link "base_laser") is missing the required `<geometry>` element. You also need to specify a joint between the two links, otherwise the robot_state_publisher will complain that there are two root links. Below are working versions of the URDF and launch file. Also see the [URDF XML documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML) and the [URDF tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/).

**URDF file:**

```
<robot name="your_robot_name">
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.15 0 0.35"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://pr2_description/meshes/head_v0/head_pan.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="base_link_to_base_laser_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="base_laser"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 1.0"/>
  </joint>
  
  <link name="base_laser">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.6" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
</robot>
```

**launch file:**

```
<launch>
  <!-- upload urdf -->
  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find your_package_name)/urdf/your_robot.urdf" />
 
  <!-- robot state publisher -->
  <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" />

  <!-- joint state publisher with gui -->
  <param name="use_gui" value="true" />
  <node pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" name="joint_state_publisher"/>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2011-04-26**:
Please post a new question with all of the relevant XML.

**Comment by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) on 2011-04-26**:
I am not sure if I need to ask new question or extend it. I see on similar issue strace output like this: stat64("/home/it/ros/visualization_common/ogre_tools/media/materials/programs/package://xml/Roboti_algus - roomuk-1 Jalg-1 1-1.STL"... Why "package://" is not parsed/rewritten? Some trick?

**Comment by [PrasadNR](https://answers.ros.org/users/28296/prasadnr/) on 2016-12-16**:
+1 But, I would still like to know how a model created in Catia/Blender (say a simple two joint three link structure hand equivalent) can be simulated in ROS Gazebo interface through C++ code (from scratch).

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2020-06-19**:
Hello, I see that you declare the base_laser link in the urdf file, but is it possible to declare it using tf package and in the urdf file just declare the base_link with the stl model?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2020-06-19**:
Sure, you can have a URDF that only has the `base_laser` link in it, and publish the TF transform yourself. If you want to display meshes for both the `base_laser` and `base_link` while publishing the `base_link` to `base_laser` joint yourself via TF, you cannot simply delete the `base_link_to_base_laser_joint`, because URDF doesn't allow two unconnected trees of links. Instead, you should change the joint type from `fixed` to `floating`. This will cause `robot_state_publisher` to ignore that joint and not publish TFs for it: https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/blob/d8600f658aa09c3cb68f034feec357dc1d24bb72/src/robot_state_publisher.cpp#L66

Then you can publish that TF yourself.

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2020-06-22**:
Okay, I understood it perfectly. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Was the stl generated from Solidworks?  If so, it might be related to [this ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4740).  We can reopen the ticket and submit a patch to assimp if necessary.

Can you please post the stl file as well?  To check, you can copy another working stl (e.g. from pr2_description) into auriga_model, and see if a different stl brings up correctly.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-03-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1